# php: pecl_http timeout < 1 is not obeyed

Tags: php, curl, timeout, connect-timeout

I am using 2.5.5 version of pecl_http library in my code (https://mdref.m6w6.name/http).

```
$httpRequest = new \http\Client\Request("GET", $url);
$httpRequest->setOptions(["timeout"=>0.5]);
$client = new \http\Client;
$client->enqueue($httpRequest)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();
```

If I set the timeout to 0.5 (500 milliseconds), it seems to return immediately on connection timeout. If I set it to say > 1, it seems to obey the timeout.

Is it a known issue?

Comment: Possibly an issue.  It does use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` under the hood so it should work.  I'm not quite clear on how it's failing though, can you clarify?